# ScheduledFuture vs Future - what is the big difference?

Tags: java

submit() method from ExecutorService interface returns interface Future (actually I think FutureTask class), while schedule() method of interface ScheduledExecutorService returns ScheduledFuture interface (actually I don't know which class, probably same FutureTask).

The only difference is that ScheduledFuture also implements Delayed interface and has getDelay method.

But what is the principal idea - why it is ScheduledFuture and not just Future that is used with ScheduledExecutorService ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ScheduledFuture` also implements `Delayed` interface, which has method:

```
long getDelay(TimeUnit unit);
```

Javadoc says:

> Returns the remaining delay associated with this object, in the
>        given time unit.

So it make it possible for you to get this `delay`. So task implementing this interface has this `delay` property, for executor this means that it couldn't be executed before this delay passes, meanwhile `Future` doesn't have such property and can be executed once threadpool(or whatever executor you are using) is ready to execute it.